# Remote control a computer using hardware instead of software

Tags: usb, vga, remote-control

I have 3 laptops, I name them Fujitsu, Asus and Dell. I use mostly the Fujitsu, but I want to remote control the Dell without any software installation, or even executing a piece of software (at the Dell computer).

I want to do it by using the Asus laptop or any other piece of hardware (Rpi, etc.). There will be of course installed software for remote control at the Asus laptop, but NOT at the Dell computer. I could imagine something like the following:

The Asus could connect by USB with the DELL to emulate the mouse and the keyboard. The display output of the DELL (through the VGA output port that the computer has) has to be somehow input to the Asus. Me from distance, I would with the Fujitsu laptop remotely control the Asus computer, that sees the screen of the Dell. When I write something the the remotelly controlled Asus, it will send it through the USB to the DELL computer. The Dell computer will just "think" that there is just a USB keybord/mouse and a screen connected to the VGA output port.

Do not ask why I want it this way.... long and boring story. In short, the DELL computer has the administrator account locked, and I am working on it by using a "standard user" account. I cannot install or execute any software. I have to travel to an other country but I simply cannot take the Dell with me, it needs a fast ethernet in order for the VPN that it is using to function properly.

Comment: Windows has a Remote Desktop client on certain versions of Windows, you don't indicate what version(s) of Windows you have installed, nor do you even indicate what operating system(s) you are using.  There are hundreds of remote desktop clients that don't require you to actually install them and 100% portable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is called a KVM IP Switch, for example the [Adderlink AL-IPEPS](http://www.adder.com/products/adderlink-ipeps) device (I have not used this device and I have no association with Adderlink; it's just the first one I found that should do the job you want). But it will cost you a few hundred dollars.

Comment: What do you think of that device that I found in [amazon](http://www.amazon.com/HP-KVM-Adatper-CAC-AF629A/dp/B00JFC5SUG) ? I cannot really figure out what it exactly does but I imagined that I can connect it to the Dell computer and then control it globally. Can you confirm if I am right? I would like to order it if so.

Comment: I can't find much about it online, but I suspect it's just a set of cables to connect a KVM switch to a PC, and doesn't have KVM functionality itself.